# IMAGE function does not load image from URL - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to load images from some URL in Google Sheet with the function `IMAGE(URL,4,100,100)`. It's quite weird as some images do not show up due to the http, https (This mean if I switch the link of a a not-show-up image to http or https, the image appears. I loaded both of them from the same source (cloudinary), and both the http and the https link work well if I paste them on browser.
Any one have a solution? Or at least a way to sort which images are shown with http, and which are shown with https?

Comment: whats the url??

Comment: Like this: https://res.cloudinary.com/dnexx8krt/image/upload/v1584797332/tempo/WMT503MYZ-VN_503myz_6fa52e2364184799a5206fea4cc48.jpg

Comment: `IMAGE(URL,4,100,100)` works perfectly for me with the link you provided.

Comment: Yeah sometimes, it works for me, too. It's really weird. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4949665?hl=en 
Seems someone mentioned it here, too.